# Conditional RewriteBase

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using Apache 2.4 with `mod_rewrite`, and I have a problem I can't solve.

I have a `.htaccess` file containing

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    ... RewriteRules ...
</IfModule>
```

This works nicely. Now I need to do the following: If somebody accesses my website as http://my.web.page.com, I need `RewriteBase /` as in the example above. But if somebody accesses the website as http://192.168.1.10/xyz, I need `RewriteBase /xyz` instead.

I guess I can use `<If expression>...</If>` to achieve this, but I've not been able to write the expression correctly.

The `xyz` is a fixed string. It doesn't have to be copied from the URL, but can be hard-coded in the `RewriteBase /xyz` command.

How can I do this?

**EDIT**

@anubhava suggested an expression, which I couldn't get to work. So I tried some very simple `<If...>` statements that simply use the `RewriteBase /` statement.

I am now very, very confused.

**Attempt 1**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

<If "false">
  RewriteBase /
</If>
```

This works. So far so good. Now let's enable the conditional:

**Attempt 2**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

<If "true">
  RewriteBase /
</If>
```

This does not work. So enabling the conditional makes a difference. Perhaps the two `RewriteBase` statements cause the code to fail.

**Attempt 3**

```
RewriteEngine On

<If "true">
  RewriteBase /
</If>
```

Nope, this still doesn't work. Perhaps it is the mere presence of the conditional that is a problem?

**Attempt 4**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

<If "true">
  #RewriteBase /
</If>
```

This works. So the conditional itself is harmless. I just can't write `RewriteBase` inside it.

For completeness sake, the rewrite rules I'm using are:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

The Apache error log contains no error information.

**SECOND EDIT**

Based on the suggestions from @anubhava, I managed to get this to work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# case 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =my.web.page.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

# case 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^192\.168\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ xyz/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Why? Maybe just put an .htaccess file inside `xyz` and redirect to that URL if the request is for /xyz.

Comment: I can't do that, @PanamaJack. The URLs http://my.web.page.com and http://192.168.1.10/xyz point to the same directory. I need a single piece of code that works with two different URLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your edited question these rules should work:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# case 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =my.web.page.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

# case 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^192\.168\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ xyz/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Lifesaver answer @anubhava

Comment: Is there a way to do conditional RewriteBase instead of condition RewriteRule?

Comment: No that's not possible